# Copy/paste entire column with blanks from filtered table

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a macro that imports data from a CSV file into a table, filters out all but one category, copies what's left, and pastes it onto a different sheet.

```
    Set rNew = NewWS.Range("M2") 'set cell where data will be pasted
    rBand.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="NFR" 'in table "rband", filter out all but NFR category
    If WorksheetFunction.Count(rBand.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) <> 0 Then
        Set rData = Generator.Sheets("Fband").Range("E2") 'select first y value
        Set rData = Range(rData, rData.End(xlDown)) 'select range of y values
        rData.Copy
        rNew.PasteSpecial
        Set rData = Generator.Sheets("Fband").Range("C2") 'select first x value
        Set rData = Range(rData, rData.End(xlDown)) 'select range of x values
        rData.Copy
        NewWS.Range("L2").PasteSpecial
    End If
```

This code works perfectly well when every cell of columns E and F in the table are filled in (i.e. theoretical data). However, when using real-world data, some of these cells will be blank. In this case, the macro will copy and paste the x values correctly, but will only copy and paste the first y value. I assume the blanks are what's causing the problem, but why would they if they're filtered out?

**More detail than may be necessary below:**
The data in question is engine vibration. Column C is frequency, E is amplitude, and F is the category ("NFR" means the vibration frequency matches the engine speed). The FFT software we use spits out raw data (in CSV format) as a list of equally-spaced (linear scale) frequencies and their amplitudes. The first part of my macro sorts these by frequencies by octave band (into log scale). Depending on the sample rate, there may be more bands than there are raw data points at low frequency; this is why some rows are blank. I want my macro to be able to ignore the blanks so that it will work on any dataset recorded at any sample rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`End(xlDown)` takes you to the first blank in the column.  Therefore, you will not always capture the entire column.  To do this, try the following code:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Set rNew = NewWS.Range("M2") 'set cell where data will be pasted
rBand.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="NFR" 'in table "rband", filter out all but NFR category
If WorksheetFunction.Count(rBand.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) <> 0 Then
    LastRow = Generator.Sheets("Fband").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rData = Generator.Sheets("Fband").Range("E2:E" & LastRow) 'select range of y value
    rData.Copy
    rNew.PasteSpecial
    LastRow = Generator.Sheets("Fband").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rData = Generator.Sheets("Fband").Range("C2:C" & LastRow) 'select range of x value
    rData.Copy
    NewWS.Range("L2").PasteSpecial
End If
```